# Get miles between two places using Bing Maps in WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to extract the miles from the HTML code after you've established directions between two places? After getting the directions, I can see the miles in the page's source code in IE and I am trying to extract the number of miles it shows by using the below. This is probably easy, but I am stumped.

A little more info. I am able to pass the WebBrowser control the places to get directions to and from and display the directions as it would in IE. I want to get the miles in a textbox.

***html code***

[image]

***VB.NET code***

```
Dim miles As String = ""
Dim minutes As String = ""
Dim strHtml As String = ""
strHtml = wbMaps.DocumentText

For i As Integer = 0 To strHtml.Length - 1
    If InStr(strHtml(i).ToString, "descriptionDistance") Then
        Dim bracketLoc As Integer = 0
        Dim closeBracketLoc As Integer = 0
        bracketLoc = InStr(strHtml(i).ToString, ">")
        closeBracketLoc = InStr(strHtml(i).ToString, "<")
        miles = Mid(strHtml(i).ToString, bracketLoc + 1, closeBracketLoc - 1)
        haulMiles = Val(miles)
        tb_Miles.Text = haulMiles.ToString
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already answered your own question, but I'll add another answer in case you're interested. Instead of writing your own parsing logic, you can get the miles much easier if you use the HtmlAgilityPack which you can add to your project via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

```
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(wbMaps.Document.Body.InnerHtml)
        miles = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@data-tag='descriptionDistance']").InnerHtml
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that info. I'll set it up tonight and play with it, in case there's more complicated information I want to get. Doing it the way that I described above - I might not be as lucky to extract things between 2 distinct keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used this:

```
    Dim miles As String = ""
    Dim minutes As String = ""
    Dim strHtml As StringBuilder

    strHtml = New StringBuilder

    strHtml.Append(wbMaps.DocumentText)

    Dim lines() As String = Split(strHtml.ToString, vbCrLf)


    For Each line As String In lines

        If InStr(line, "descriptionDistance") Then

            Dim bracketLoc As Integer = 0
            Dim closeBracketLoc As Integer = 0
            bracketLoc = InStr(line, ">")
            closeBracketLoc = InStr(line, "<")
            miles = Mid(line, bracketLoc + 1, closeBracketLoc - 1)
            haulMiles = Val(miles)
            tb_Miles.Text = miles

        End If
    Next
```